# Thread Safety of ServletContext objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am storing a HashMap object in my ServletContext.
But Multiple Request thread are reading and Modifying this HashMap.

As i belive the ServletContext objects are shared between request threads do i need to Synchronize the access to this HashMap ? Or is there any other better ways to achive the same ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Publishing attributes via `ServletContext#setAttribute` is thread-safe! This can be derived from the Java Servlet Specification, chapter 4.5: *(...) Any attribute bound 
into a context is available to any other servlet that is part of the same Web 
application.(...)*.

(Reason: Making objects available to other servlets means also to make them available to other threads. This is only possible, if proper synchronization is used, so synchronization is mandatory for all servlet containers that implement `ServletContext#setAttribute`).

So the same is also true for reading published attributes via `ServletContext#getAttribute`.

But of course if an object like a `HashMap` is shared between different threads, the developer must ensure that this shared object itself is accessed in a proper, thread-safe way! Using a `ConcurrentHashMap` as already stated in other answers of your question, is a possible solution, but does not solve the race condition when the attribute is initialized, as the `null` check will not be atomic:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Object> shared = (...)servletContext.getAttribute("sharedData");
if (shared == null) {
    shared = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    servletContext.setAttribute("sharedData", shared);
}
```

Therefore, a `ServletContextListener` can be used to initialize the context when the web application starts!

---

Edit: **To avoid confusions**

We can deduce from the *Java Servlet Specification*, that sharing attributes between servlets via `ServletContext#setAttribute` and `ServletContext#getAttribute` is indeed *thread-safe*.

But however it is implemented internally, `set/getAttribute` can only guarantee *proper publishing*, it cannot guarantee proper synchronization if the shared attribute is a modifiable object that is modifed *after sharing*. This is technically impossible!

Example:

```
// servlet 1:
Person p = new Person("Keith", "Richards");
context.setAttribute('key', p); // share p
p.setName("Ron", "Wood"); // modification AFTER sharing

// servlet 2 (some time LATER):
Person p = context.getAttribute();
// now, p is guaranteed to be non-null,
// but if class Person is not thread-safe by itself, it may be any of
// - "Keith Richards"
// - "Keith Wood"
// - "Ron Richards"
// - "Ron Wood"
// (depending on the implementation of setName, it may be even worse!)
```

As a consequence, **every** servlet context attribute value must be

- immutable (via final fields) or effectively immutable, OR
- mutable, but is never mutated after sharing, OR
- implemented in a *thread-safe* manner (e.g. synchronized)

(This is true for all kinds of objects shared between threads in Java, not only concerning servlet context attributes)

Comment: I just got confused a little with the terms. On the one hand, you say setting attributes in _ServletContext_ is thread-safe, on the other - the proper synchronization must be used. I thought, synchronization is used exactly for the purpose to protect context attributes that are NOT thread-safe. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @escudero380 what I mean is that every implementation of the _Java Servlet Specification_ **must** use proper synchronization within `setAttribute`, otherwise it cannot fullfil the cited requirement from chapter 4.5.

Comment: @escudero380 I've slightly changed the answer and added another clarification section to address this issue.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Anyway, from what I understand, context-scoped attributes mostly exist for the purpose of storing read-only values that get set when the application is being loaded, but not necessarily a good place to share request time generated values... and in a distributed environment, such attributes seem to be not accessible for the entire cluster, so with perspective of scaling up the project, some external resource like database should be used instead as location to share global information on application-level

Comment: @escudero380 I totally agree.

Answer (score 4):

As Suggested by `@Artem Moskalev`, You can use ConcurrentHashMap and use `putIfAbsent` method to store the object/values instead of simple `put` method.

*I wanted to add this comment below `@Artem Moskalev'`s answer but i don't have enough reputation for this.*

Comment: Have some rep. You'll be able to add comments in no time. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way in a multithreaded environment is to use **java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap**.
It is designed specifically in a way that allows you to read and modify it without any `ConcurrentModificationException`. Nevertheless, in case of iteration you should synchronize on its instance, in order to always get the predicatble results.

Synchronizing on the context gives you a lot of overhead, if you    retrieve anything else from there in a multithreaded manner. So `ConcurrentHashMap` is a better solution.

You can read about it here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
>   expected concurrency for updates. Retrieval operations (including get)
>   generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations
>   (including put and remove).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, make sure that when you modifying the `HashMap`; it is synchronized or thread safe.

Answer (score -1):

You need to synchronize your ServletContext object. for eg:-

```
synchronized(ctx){
 //your code here
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should not use the intrinsic (monitor) lock of an object that you do not control.